# WPF Datagrid and Access database

Tags: wpf-controls

I have a datagrid that displays data from an access database.  When I run an update query, it works, but the datagrid does not update.  After the update query runs I reset the ItemsSource.

Is there any solutions or ideas to fix this problem?

After the query runs, I call a function to fill the data grid:

```
fillDataGrid(string query)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(table);
    dgLogs.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;     
}
```

Comment: it is hard to say anything without seeing the code..

Comment: I added the code that I use to fill the datagrid.

Comment: I believed I have figured it out.  Thanks for your time.